# Process received data from python requests library to show it in template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-templates, python-requests

i am try to get live data from Raspberry pi and showing it to my django template. i could send data by 'requests' library and receiv it by Django REST. but the problem is in my django for example i post data to localhost/a how could i can render this data to localhost/b for example.

i tried django session. i thought that when i in localhost/b maybe i can use session but that dose not work.

rpi-req.py

```py
# this is code from Raspberry pi, to send(POST) data to django

while True:
    # print(cam.get_frame())
    da = {'rpiLive': "30 or any data"}
    res = requests.post(url, files=da, timeout=1000, auth=('anas', '****'))
    print(res.status_code)
    time.sleep(1)
```

views.py inside django.

```py
# this code is from django-views, to receive data
@api_view(['POST'])
def video_feed(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        reqData = request.FILES['rpiLive']
        try:
            return HttpResponse(gen22(request, reqData),
                                content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=reqData')
        except Exception as q:
            print("live Data aborted!!!", q)

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/live2/')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

And gen22 function is:

```py
def gen22(request, data):
    a = data
    time.sleep(0.5)
    con = {
        "anas": a,
        "con_tag": "live",
    }
    time.sleep(1)
    return render(request, "dahsboard.html", con)
```

urls.py

```
path('<int:user_id>/<tag>/', views.dahsboard, name='dahsboard'),
path('live/', views.video_feed, name='live-frame2'),
```

Comment: add expected output

Comment: When raspbery pi sends HTTP POST what you want to happened ? You should get back some output (What output ? same what you sent on server?). be more clear.

Comment: when raspberry send POST , django can receive data 'look at views.py'. normal data like temperature value. or any else. i send "rpiLive=30" and i can  receive it in django views. but i cant take this variable and show it to user in template!. the problem is the render in "gen22" function is not work.
i just want to use template to show the variable receive from Rasoberry.

Comment: i edited the  question by adding the urls.py. please have look to my 2 urls. i work on "/user_id/tag" . but my REST framwork send to "/live2".  in "/live2" i can receive data from raspberry but cant to show this data in "user_id/tag". @gachdavit

Comment: I do not see **/live2/** url in urls.py. I guess you mean **/live/**. Make HTTP Post request in /live/ (send data on server) and save this Data inside Database or File or somewhere. Then, read this data when you visit <int:user_id>/<tag>/...

Comment: /live/ for inserting data in Database. <int:user_id>/<tag>/ for reading and monitoring data.

Comment: no no sorry.. i dont need to save in database. just showing the data in html as live. every second rpi send data(like you the data not important. maybe just int). 
And yes in "locakhost/user_id/tag" page i want monitoring  received data in "localhost/live" page.@gachdavit